# Invoke Linux command from C is not giving any output though java

Tags: java, linux

I am executing my own customized linux from through C as below

**C code :**

```
system("service soapserver stop");
```

here here soapserver is the binary in my linux machine. Same command is executing successfully from putty but from Java when i am trying to get the output of above command its showing none.

**Java code :** Here soap_systemHelper is the another binary that hits to the corresponding c file function and execute the above command.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "soap_systemHelper 23" );
```

Please let me know what could be the reason for this that i am not getting any output.
I'll be very much thankful for your quick response.

Answer (score 2):

Use `p.getOutputStream()` to get an OutputStream from the stdout of the process. You can then read from that stream using standard Java io classes, and if you want, print the output to `System.out`.

You can also use the methods of the Process class to get error streams and exit values.

Comment: I am using soap_systemHelper 23 command from putty then it executed successfully and stop the soapserver process. but the same thing i executed from java gives not outout with no error means soapserver process still running. below is the java code :Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(“soap_systemHelper 23" );
   InputStream inStream = p.getInputStream();
   InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inReader);

Comment: when i execute Runtime.getRuntime().exec("service soapserver stop"), it shows permission denied error for executing "service" but other customized commands executed in in the same way like i have another command (/usr/vm/bin/startnpm) in my c code . this command executed successfully from java code .

Comment: Is ``soap_systemHelper`` an executable binary? Or a script? If the latter, perhaps you can try to run the script interpreter with that as the argument? Finally, have you tried using the full path name to the variable? The Java Runtime class might not be setting the path in the environment. Finally, do you need to be a privileged user to run the command? If so you will need to use ``sudo`` and ``visudo`` to allow running sudo without a password.

Comment: soap_systemHelper is a binary. I have not tried the command "service soapserver stop" using full path name

Comment: You will get a permission denied when running service because it is owned by root, and (I assume) you are running the JVM as an unprivileged user.

Comment: yes all command needs root permission and i am not able to run any command from java because of the root permission issue. but i have given 4711 permission to soap_systemHelper binary and using this binary , i am able to execute root commands by passing integer argument to soap_systemHelper <interger> . this integer number hits to my C file function and gives the output. But i tried to put the log in my case before and after executing the soap_systemHelper 23 command which are printing also do not getting any logs in catch block.

Comment: that's why i am not able to trace what could be the reason for that and how to trace that if command executed or not because soapserver is still running.

Comment: also sir , how is it possible that the same command is running from putty but not running from java and also not throwing any error (means code is getting bypass). Any solution how to trace this issue.I'll be thankful for your support